# How to append each single value from a dictionary list into its own column?

Tags: list, dictionary, append, refactoring, sankey-diagram

This is the dictionary I have and I wanted to put every single value from the list into its own column.

```
my_dict  = {1: ['Home', 'Stories'], 2: ['Sounds', 'Stories', 'Home', 'Home', 'Stories'], 3: ['Journeys', 'Journeys', 'Journeys '], 4: [ 'Home', 'Home', 'Home'], 5: ['Home', 'Stories', 'Home', 'Home', 'Cancellation Flow'], 6: ['My Account', 'My Account']}
```

I would like my output to look like this:

```
User       1                  2                  3               4        5
1          'Home'            'Stories'
2          'Sounds'          'Stories'          'Home'          'Home'   'Stories'
3          'Journeys'        'Journeys'         'Journeys'
4          'Home'            'Home'             'Home'
5          'Home'            'Stories'          'Home'          'Home'   'Cancellation Flow'
6          'My Account'      'My Account'
```

Does anyone have any tips on how to do this. I wanted to make a sankey graph and need each singular click decision (each item of the list) as its own column in order to see the combination of each of these click decisions.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage from [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html) lib which can automate a lot of efforts for such kind of tasks with concise code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index').fillna('')\
    .rename_axis(['User']).reset_index()
df.columns = [df.columns[0], *(df.columns[1:] + 1)]
print(df)
```

---

```
   User           1           2          3     4                  5
0     1        Home     Stories                                    
1     2      Sounds     Stories       Home  Home            Stories
2     3    Journeys    Journeys  Journeys                          
3     4        Home        Home       Home                         
4     5        Home     Stories       Home  Home  Cancellation Flow
5     6  My Account  My Account
```